# Making Json request to use two "names" in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following methods that I want to use in my controller:

```
  def store
    "#{business_name} - #{address}" if self.online_store == false
  end

  def webstore
    "#{business_name} - #{website}" if self.online_store == true
  end
```

Right now I am using only 1 of them:

```
format.json { render :json => @business_stores.collect{|b|{:id => b.id, :name => b.store } } }
```

I need the `:name` to search for `b.store` and `b.webstore`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create only one method

```
def store
  if self.online_store == false
    "#{business_name} - #{address}"
  else
    "#{business_name} - #{website}"
  end  
end
```

And when you will ask for it will know if it's the online store or not

Comment: Yep. Better solution. I'd have use a ternary operator here to make the method more compact.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul Thanks, even better and what I wanted to do eventually. Still learning RoR as I go.

Comment: why keep the non-idiomatic `== false`? @wrbg: is this a AR boolean attribute? if it is: `self.online_store?`

Comment: I kept the `==false` because in the question posted it was used.

Comment: @tokland Yeah I changed it to not use the false. So no worries, thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 2):

```
def store
  if self.online_store
    "#{business_name} - #{website}"
  else
    "#{business_name} - #{address}"
  end  
end
```

You need not even use `== false` since it is already boolean.